# Get-Winevent Filterhashtable Formatting error

Tags: powershell

When I try to run this script:

```
$Filename = ""U:\logfile_analysis\raw_data\SavedSecurity.evtx""
$EventIDsLogon.ToString() = "4624"
$EventIDsLogoff.ToString() = "4647"
$EventIDsLogonFailure.ToString() = "4625"
$EventIDsLockScreen.ToString() = "4800"
$EventIDsUnlockScreen.ToString() = "4801"
$EventIDstemp = $EventIDsLogon, $EventIDsLogoff, $EventIDsLogonFailure, $EventIDsLockScreen, $EventIDsUnlockScreen -join ","
$EventIDsSummary = $EventIDstemp.Trim()
#Write-Host $EventIDsSummary
Write-Host "Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path='$Filename'; ID=$EventIDsSummary}"
pause
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path='$Filename'; ID=$EventIDsSummary}
```

and look at the output from

```
Write-host "Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path='$Filename'; ID=$EventIDsSummary}"
```

the ouput is:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path='U:\logfile_analysis\raw_data\SavedSecurity.evtx'; ID=4624,4647,4625,4800,4801}
```

When I copy the output from `Write-Host` to a PowerShell console it works:

```
PS> Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path='U:\logfile_analysis\raw_data\SavedSecurity.evtx'; ID=4624,4647,4625,4800,4801}


    ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing

    TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
    -----------                     -- ---------------- -------
    04.12.2017 13:56:56           4624 Informationen    Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet...
    04.12.2017 13:56:56           4647 Informationen    Benutzerinitiierte Abmeldung:...
    04.12.2017 13:56:48           4801 Informationen    Die Arbeitsstation wurde entsperrt...
    04.12.2017 13:56:48           4624 Informationen    Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet...
    04.12.2017 13:56:48           4624 Informationen    Ein Konto wurde erfolgreich angemeldet...
******** truncated ****
```

But:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path='$Filename'; ID=$EventIDsSummary}
```

did not work.

Error Message is:

> Get-WinEvent : Cannot find path 'U:\logfile_analysis\$Filename' because it does not exist.

I tried to add `""` at `@{Path="$Filename"...`.
I tried to add `''` at `@Path="$Filename"...`.
I tried to manipulate the `$Filename  variable and add`""`, the variable`$Filename` looks like

```
$Filename = '"U:\logfile_analysis\raw_data\SavedSecurity.evtx"'
$Filename = ""U:\logfile_analysis\raw_data\SavedSecurity.evtx""
$Filename = "'U:\logfile_analysis\raw_data\SavedSecurity.evtx'"
```

No success.

A deeper look shows the problem, `@Path='$Filename'`
The path must be within two "", how can I add them that the script works?

Comment: as easy as `$Filename="U:\logfile_analysis\raw_data\SavedSecurity.evtx" ; Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path=$Filename; ID=$EventIDsSummary}`

Comment: In addition to what Michel said, you need to make the value of the key `ID` an actual array, not a comma-delimited string: `$EventIDsSummary = 4624, 4647, 4625, 4800, 4801`. Also, `$var.ToString() = "..."` can't possibly work and should have given you a "cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" error.

Comment: thanks for the hints. i cannot get it running when creating an array `EventIDstemp=@($EventIDsLogon, $EventIDsLogoff, $EventIDsLogonFailure, $EventIDsLockScreen, $EventIDsUnlockScreen -join ",")` and run `Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path=$Filename; ID=$EventsIDstemp}`. no idea, why. `echo $EventIDstemp` gives `4624,4647,4625,4800,4801`, Errormessage is `Get-WinEvent : A null value was encountered in the ID hash table key. Null values are not permitted.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your hints @/lo%c3%afc-michel and @ansgar-wiechers. I think i solved it with the following Code:

```
$Filename="c:\temp"
$EventIDsLogon="4624"
$EventIDsLogoff="4647"
$EventIDsLogonFailure="4625"
$EventIDsLockScreen="4800"
$EventIDsUnlockScreen="4801"
$EventIDstemp=@($EventIDsLogon,$EventIDsLogoff,$EventIDsLogonFailure,$EventIDsLockScreen, $EventIDsUnlockScreen) 
echo $Filename
echo $EventIDstemp
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path=$Filename; ID=$EventIDstemp}
```